# TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, google-oauth

I'm trying to link my React Native app to firebase Google Auth. After I linked the Library to the app manually via XCode, the iOS simulator returns type error **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null, js engine: hermes"**. [Error in iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTBIs.png)

Below is the function of `react.development.js` where the error occurred.

```js
...
function useState(initialState) {
  var dispatcher = resolveDispatcher();
  return dispatcher.useState(initialState); // error occurred in this line
}
...
```

I'm wondering how to fix this error.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain you don't have multiple versions of React or React-Native installed?

Comment: Did you by any chance upgrade react-native-permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You might have 2 versions of `React` in the project. Check with `yarn` and make sure that you only have a single version.

Suggestion: It looks like `resolveDispatcher` is returning null. You can create your own hook.